# equivalence classes of a language via myhill nerode

Tags: equivalence-relations

My task is to find equivalence classes for different languages based on Myhill-Nerode. I'm having a hard time finding these equivalence classes; for example, the language $L = {b^∗a^n | n ≡ 0 mod 5}$ with alphabet {a,b}.

My first solution would be:
$[ϵ]
[b^*]
[b^*a]
[b^*aa]
[b^*aaa]
[b^*aaaa]$

Would these be the correct classes? If not, i would appreciate any help!